# Choosing school activities

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

The problem text is :

> There are $4$ afternoon activities in a school: theater, music, mosaic, creative writing. In the middle of the year $7$ new students arrive. How many ways can they each choose an activity so that each activity is chosen by at least one of the new students?

---

I used the Sylvester's formula and got the result $\sum_{i=0}^{4}(-1)^i(4-i)^7\binom{4}{i}$ but the solution says it's $\sum_{i=0}^{4}(4-i)^7\binom{4}{i}$.

What am I getting wrong?

Comment: What is $n$?  With the way the question is written, both are wrong since $n$ is meaningless.

Comment: Once the issue with $n$ is corrected, the one with $(-1)^i$ will be the correct one... it coming about because of inclusion-exclusion.

Answer (score 4):

Since both students and activities are distinguishable. Then this is simply the number of surjective functions $f:\{a,b,c,d,e,f,g\}\to\{1,2,3,4\}$. You use PIE to get the result, which is $$\sum_{k=0}^4(-1)^k\binom{4}{k}(4-k)^7.$$

Comment: Since you see now that both students and activities are distinguishable, why keep the first half of your answer?  Remove that as it is irrelevant.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense.